# xargs substition of more than one argument

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

By default `xargs` will concatenate many lines of its input and pass then to the specified command.  For example:

```
echo -e 'line 1\nline 2\nline 3' | xargs echo
```

results in

```
line 1 line 2 line 3
```

Since the arguments are sent to a single echo command (within the limits of the command line length).

Sometimes you want to use replacement string to put the arguments somewhere else in the command, rather than the end:

```
echo -e 'line 1\nline 2\nline 3' | xargs -Ix echo x DONE
line 1 DONE
line 2 DONE
line 3 DONE
```

Now, xargs only substituted one argument per each echo invocation, because as the man page says "-I implies -L 1...". That's probably the right behavior for a typical case, but is there any way to override it, so I get `line 1 line 2 line 3 DONE` as the output?

Please note that my example is illustrative only - I'm not very interested in non-xargs ways of tacking this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of an `xargs` option which will do that, but you can achieve something similar with an invocation of `bash -c`:

```
$ echo -e "line 1\nline    2\nline 3" | xargs bash -c 'echo "${@}" DONE' _
line 1 line 2 line 3 DONE
```

Note that `xargs` does not provide the *lines* as arguments, even if you specify `-L`. You might want to use `-d` to specify that new-line separates items (gnu xargs only, I believe). Contrast the following:

```
$ echo -e "line 1\nline    2\nline 3" |
  xargs bash -c 'printf "<%s>\n" "${@}" DONE' _
<line>
<1>
<line>
<2>
<line>
<3>
<DONE>

$ echo -e "line 1\nline    2\nline 3" |
  xargs -d\\n bash -c 'printf "<%s>\n" "${@}" DONE' _
<line 1>
<line    2>
<line 3>
<DONE>
```

Comment: Good point about how xargs is breaking up args, on whitespace boundaries, not line boundaries (although lines are special for arguments like -L and hence implicitly for -I).

Comment: @BeeOnRope: even with -L, xargs breaks arguments on wordspace. The line count specifies the number of lines containing arguments but the lines are not otherwise treated specially.

Comment: Right, that's why I said "lines are special" not that xargs changes the way it breaks up arguments, but that it does use lines to initially chunk the input into invocations, then proceeds to break up on whitespace as usual.

Comment: echo -e "line 1\nline    2\nline 3" | parallel echo :{}:

Answer (score 2):

Convert newlines into `\nul` terminators, then use `xargs -0`

```
$ echo -ne 'line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n' | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -Ix echo x DONE
line 1 DONE
line 2 DONE
line 3 DONE
```

Comment: As above, I got the same output already without the tr and -0 (it is not needed here).  The issue is that I want it all on one line: `line 1 DONE line 2 DONE ...`

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
arg=$( echo -e 'line 1\nline 2\nline 3' | xargs )
echo $arg Done.
```

I used this construct to generate a multiple page PDF-file from many single PDFs:

```
arg=$( find -mmin -60 -type f -name "*.pdf" | xargs )
pdftk $arg cat output AllMyRecentPDFs.pdf
```

Comment: The question is about using `xargs` to that effect.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question, I think you just want to convert newlines to a non-delimiter.

> echo -ne 'foo\nbar\nbaz' | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs -I{} echo {} DONE

Comment: No, I want each of foo, bar and baz to be unique arguments. The example is artificial - the point is to be able to put something *after* the arguments added by xargs.

Comment: That's what you'll get. For example, `ls | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs -I{} echo {} DONE` yields `dir1/ dir2/ dir3/  DONE`.

Comment: No, in that case the entire string "dir1/ dir2/ dir3/" is passed as a single argument to echo, which is not what I want. Yes the output is the same in my toy example, but in real life I'm not passing to echo.

Try your example but passing it to a version of echo that quotes all the arguments (for example) and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Then what you want can't be done just with xargs options, I don't think. (Also, though I see what you mean now, it's very unclear that this is what you intend from your original post, given the example you include).